# How do I add a map without changing the configuration?

Tags: angular, esri

I should add map to my site and I using ANGULAR 2 and ESRI . 
Is there such a possibility in the normal way , not by changing the configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a blog post on using angular and esri [Using AngularJS with the ESRI JavaScript API](http://justinchmura.com/2014/06/16/using-angularjs-esri-javascript-api/). You just need to adapt the code to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by changing configuration, but here's a great place to start. ESRI folks wrote some directives you can drop into your project:

https://github.com/Esri/angular-esri-map#what-about-angular-2

Here's a quick example with getting started with a Feature Layer:
http://esri.github.io/angular-esri-map/#/examples/feature-layer